# How to prevent some files in project folder from being committed to Github

Tags: git, github

If I am working on a project and their are some files that should not be committed to Github (reference notes that are specific to me for instance) because they do not relate or would have no significance at all to anyone else.

Is there a way to leave the files in the project folder locally, but not include them when the folder is pushed to Github?

Comment: isn't .gitignore enough?

Comment: google `.gitignore` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use a .gitignore file. Place a file with the name `.gitignore` in the root folder of your repository.  In it list the files and any folders you want to exclude from version control.  Here's an example of a few lines in a .gitignore file I use:

```
# Compiler outputs #
*.a
*.bat
*.exe

# Directories #
API_Parser_Output
Obj

# Packages #
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
```

If you google .gitignore you should find more examples if needed